# My selenium bot is not being allowed to sign into Gmail

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gmail, bots

Ok so, I'm making a python bot, that signs me into Gmail. But when the bot types everything in, it says it cannot sign me in because the browser is not secure.

[This is what it shows me after trying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpYJz.png)

Is there something else I have to do? I have tried a couple of times...would they be able to detect that it is an automated software? Thanks.

Comment: _would they be able to detect that it is an automated software?_ That's probably what's happening, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Google forbids using automated scripts for logging into Gmail.

> To help protect your account, Google doesn’t let you sign in from some browsers. Google might stop sign-ins from browsers that:
>
> - Don’t support JavaScript or have Javascript turned off.
> - Have unsecure or unsupported extensions added.
> - **Use automation testing frameworks.**
> - Are embedded in a different application.

See: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7675428?hl=en

You have to use their API if you want to automate Gmail.